# How do I to change function from using mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm switching to mysqli for my cms, and I've having some problems switching my query & fetch function to mysqli, I keep getting errors that say

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 48 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 49 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 48 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 49  Warning: mysqli_real_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 41 Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 41
```

I've tried different quires like so :

```
function query($query) {
    $sql = mysqli_real_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
    return $sql;
    mysqli_free_result($sql);

}

function fetch($query) {
    $data = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    return($data);
}

2:
function query($query) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    return $sql;
    mysqli_free_result($sql);

}

function fetch($query) {
    $data = mysqli_query($this->db, $query);
    mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    return($data);
}
```

I've keep getting the same errors, and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or what. Could you help me and give me some tips please?, my orginal code before trying to use mysqli

```
function query($query) {
    $sql = mysql_query($query, $this->db) or die(mysql_error());
    return $sql;
    mysql_free_result($sql);
}



function fetch($query) {
    $sql = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query, $this->db));
    return $sql;
    mysql_free_result($sql);

}
```

Comment: $connection and $this->db are null, do you have more code to show where those are being set or are they missing? Are these functions inside of a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make a connection and db name

```
$this->con = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);
mysqli_select_db( $this->con,$this->db );
```

then execute query like this

```
function query_execute( $query )
{
    $this->query = mysqli_query( $this->con,$query );
    if ($this->query->num_rows > 0 ) {
        return $this->query;
    } else {
        return mysqli_error( $this->con );
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work but I get this error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/include/header.php on line 56` here's line 56-60: `if ($account['id']) {
    $id = $account['id'];
} else {
    $id = '-1';
}`